# Why am I getting "Connection property has not been initialized" here?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

1.ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized".
2.this is the error wen I execute the below code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=Sadiq;Initial Catalog=rafi;Integrated Security=True";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "student";
            int studid = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            string name = TextBox2.Text;
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
            string school = TextBox4.Text;
            string clas = TextBox5.Text;
            int marks = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text);
            string grade = TextBox7.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stud_id", studid));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", name));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@age", age));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@school", school));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@class", clas));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@marks", marks));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@grade", grade));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You didn't tell `cmd` which connection to use. Pass it as an argument to `new SqlCommand()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to do:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

before executing the query. It needs a connection to execute against.

You could also refactor it a bit to be:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("student", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

instead of:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "student";
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

That overload sets the `CommandText` and `Connection` properties via the constructor.

You also need to wrap all of those ADO.NET objects in the `using` statement. I explain it in detail on a [blog post of mine](http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/).